# Compute the Euler function $\phi(n)$ for $n = 360$ as well as the number of divisors $d(n)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, divisibility, totient-function, divisor-counting-function

Compute the Euler function $\phi(n)$ for $n = 360 $ as well as the number of
divisors $d(n)$.

Is this correct?

$360 = 2^3\cdot 3^2\cdot 5$ thus $\phi(n) = 2^2\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4 = 96$.

$d(n) = 4 \times 3 \times 2 = 24$.

Comment: It's correct. If $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\cdots p_n^{\alpha_n}$ is the unique prime factorization of $n$, then $\phi(n)=p_1^{\alpha_1-1}(p_1-1)p_2^{\alpha_2-1}(p_2-1)\cdots p_n^{\alpha_n-1}(p_n-1)$ and $d(n)=(\alpha_1+1)(\alpha_2+1)\cdots (\alpha_n+1)$.

Comment: Why the downvotes. I am new. What should i have done differentely?

Comment: @MrOldman I don't know why you were downvoted. You gave a clear statement of the problem, of your working, and of your question. (I also don't know why my answer of "You are correct" was so heavily panned by the critics.)

Comment: @MrOldman You wrote $\phi(n)=2^2234$. Use \cdot or \times inbetween, like you did in $d(n)=4\times 3\times 2=24$. There's only one downvoter. I'm not sure why.

Comment: @user236182 Ok, my professor uses that notation thats why i did that. But now i know how to do it here.

Comment: @MrOldman It could be confused with $2^2\cdot 234=936$ while it should be $2^2\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4$. It's ok not to write \cdot or \times when there's an exponent, e.g. you can write $2^23^2$, but you clearly shouldn't write $23$ to denote $2\cdot 3$. You could also write $\phi(n)=2^2(2)(3)(4)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$360 = 2^3\times 3^2\times5$. Since Euler Phi function is multiplicative, $\phi(360)=\phi(8)\times\phi(9)\times\phi(5)=(8-4)\times(9-3)\times4=96.$

Which means you are correct.

Comment: I think you mean "Since Euler is multiplicative", rather than "Hence…"

Comment: 'Euler' is not multiplicative...'Euler Phi Function' is...:-)

Comment: @tatan I guess Euler was multiplicative enough, he had 13 children.

Answer (score 0):

[Euler Phi Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) is a method for calculation the number of integers less than and co prime to a particular integer.

Let,$n$ be an integer such that $n=p_1^{a_1}\times p_2^{a_2}\times p_3^{a_3}\times...p_n^{a_n}$.

$\phi(n)=n(1-\frac{1}{p_1})(1-\frac{1}{p_2})...(1-\frac{1}{p_n})$

Just plug in the values to get your answer.

Answer (score -2):

You are correct, although note that you're better using \times or \cdot rather than just a space, because in LaTeX (and MathJax) a space will be omitted.

Comment: I would like to know why this was downvoted. Am I wrong?